# QDockWidget hide title bar

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4

I can't find how to hide the title bar of my Qdockwidgets :

I have found this on the references :

```
QDockWidget.setTitleBarWidget (self, QWidget widget)

The widget argument has it's ownership transferred to Qt.

Sets an arbitrary widget as the dock widget's title bar. If widget is 0, any custom title bar widget previously set on the dock widget is removed, but not deleted, and the default title bar will be used instead.
```

And this in quite a few places :

```
dockWidget->setTitleBarWidget(new QWidget());
```

but how to actually use them ? I simply can't find any simple example of code showing those in action not even in the references and all of my tries ended up with various errors. 
In the whole page : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget there is simply nothing which tell me how I can use this :

```
QDockWidget.setTitleBarWidget (self, QWidget widget)
```

If I read the documentation I should replace the "widget" one by a 0 so I get no title bar displayed

```
self.dockWdg1.setTitleBarWidget(self, QtGui.QWidget(0))# If I don't add QtGui in front of QWidget it don't know what is QWidget
```

give me this error :

```
TypeError: QWidget(QWidget parent=None, Qt.WindowFlags flags=0): argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'
```

Another question, is there actually people using this references : ? http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qdockwidget.html#setTitleBarWidget

My question can seem weird but I find thoses references so incomplete (no code example) and the explanations so obscures I really wonder if I am looking on the right one, especially when on the other side we have this : http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/PySide/QtGui/QDockWidget.html#PySide.QtGui.QDockWidget with pySide which seems so so so so so much better. PyQT references succeed in being even worst than MaxScript references which is not a little thing to do.

My complete code :

```
import sys, random
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt4.QtGui import QPalette, QBrush, QPixmap





class MainWin(QtGui.QMainWindow):

     def __init__(self):
        super(MainWin, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()


     def initUI(self):


        #central widget
        self.theboard = Board(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.theboard)


          #dock1 Left Dock
        self.dockWdg1 = LeftDock(self)
        #Use SizeQWidget()  to define the initial size of QDockWidget
        self.content1 = SizeQWidget()
        self.dockWdg1.setWidget(self.content1)
        self.dockWdg1.setFeatures(self.dockWdg1.NoDockWidgetFeatures)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.dockWdg1)
        self.dockWdg1.setTitleBarWidget(self, QtGui.QWidget(0))# If I don't add QtGui in front of QWidget it don't know what is QWidget

        self.resize(360, 760)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test')
        self.show()



class LeftDock(QtGui.QDockWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(LeftDock, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initLeftDock()


    def initLeftDock(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 200, 120)
        #self.setWindowTitle('LeftDock')




class Board(QtGui.QFrame):


    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(Board, self).__init__(parent)

        self.initBoard()

    def initBoard(self):

        print("ddd")


#Dummy QWidget used by QDockWidget for defining initial size.
class SizeQWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
       def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(100, 75)



def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    mw = MainWin()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PyQt docs are automatically created from the C++ docs. I always just use the C++ docs.

The docs are thus not of very good overall quality.

Now to your main issue at hand.

Note that `QtGui.QWidget` takes a `QObject*` as first parameter (the parent of the newly created object). Also note that a null pointer is represented in Python by `None`, not `0`.

Then we need to know that `self` is usually implicitly passed by calling the method on an instance. (`self` in the context of PyQt is just like every other `self` you will ever encounter in Python).

Thus, this works:

```
        self.dockWdg1.setTitleBarWidget(QtGui.QWidget(None))
```

Personally I would do this a little bit different:

```
        self.dockWdg1.setTitleBarWidget(QtGui.QWidget(self.dockWdg1))
```

That is, setting the parent of the title bar widget to the dock widget itself, preserving a nice object hierarchy.

I might also remark that "removing" the title bar widget of a dock widget by replacing it with an invisible (size is zero) widget **it becomes impossible to float the dock widget**.

Comment: I see, so you use the original C++ doc... for python ... ? Do you have a C++ background ? I admit I have not yet look seriously at the C++ one, I didn't thought it was close enought to be useful in python, I will certainly have a look next time ! 
I am quite new to python as you may have seen, so if the doc say "put a 0 here" well, it is exactly what I am doing, now I will know by "0" the doc wanted to say "null" which mean "None" in python... thanks!
I don't want to float the dockwidgets I just use a mainWindow to organise diferent static panels next to each other : ) Thanks a lot!

Comment: I am getting a warning message though : QWidget::setMinimumSize: (/QDockWidget) Negative sizes (0,-1) are not possible . It is all working well apart this warning.

Comment: Yes, but knowing to write C++ is not necessary. Since the API is ~99.9 % the same it's mostly about looking up function names and their parameters, which mostly works w/o deeper knowledge of C++.

Comment: I don't get that warning here. Python 3.4.1 / PyQt4.11.2.

Comment: Ok, well, thanks for the advise on the doc. I will just ignore this warning for now as anyway the code works perfectly. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

i use this to hide them all in c++

```
for (auto &dock:findChildren<QDockWidget*>())
  dock->setTitleBarWidget(new QWidget);
```